# Apache - block request but only when three keywords are not present in the query string

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, webserver

I need to return 403 for any GET request that contains example *select, md5, declare, drop* and similar, but only when following three keywords are not present in *QUERY_STRING* (*key1, key2* and *keyx*).

Current situation (it works fine if either: name or type or value does not exist in query string):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)/key1|key2|keyx/($|&) 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(phpunit|md5|benchmark|union|cast|declare|drop).* [NC]
```

Basically all I need is to bypass the rule on second line when there are all three keywords present in query string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use these 2 conditions:

```sh
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)(key1|key2|keyx)\b [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \b(phpunit|md5|benchmark|union|cast|declare|drop)\b [NC]
```

- `\b` is for word boundary
- mod_rewrite patterns don't allow `/.../` notation like Javascript
- grouping was wrong in your attempt
- There is no need to match `.*` before and after keywords